# How to stop printing all iterations and only show true ones

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, foreach, iteration

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Collections; 

public class JMUnit2Ch10
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>(); 

        System.out.print("How many random numbers between 1 and 100:");
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int numOfNumbers = stdIn.nextInt(); 

        for(int i=0; i<numOfNumbers; i++)
        {
            randomNumbers.add((int)(Math.random()*100)+1);  
        }

        System.out.print("Which random number are your searching for?:"); 
        int searchNumber = stdIn.nextInt(); 
        System.out.printf("%n");
        for(int a: randomNumbers)
        {
            System.out.println("Unsorted List");
            System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(searchNumber)); 
        }
        Collections.sort(randomNumbers);

        for(int b:randomNumbers)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorted List");
            System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(searchNumber));  
        }
        System.out.println(randomNumbers.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum()); 
    }
}
```

I tried using a boolean value to only show if found the code i used was:

```
 boolean found = false;
```

then in the two print statements I put:

```
found=true;
```

and at the bottom put:

```
if(!found)
{
    System.out.println(randomNumbers.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum());
}
```

And was still getting output for every single iteration of the for each loop. What I am trying to do is get a single output for EACH time in the `ArrayList` that the number appears in both the sorted and unsorted `ArrayList`s then a sum of all numbers in the array list.

Edit1: The current output I am getting is the `searchNumber` where it is for how many numbers there are so it is outputting `x` amount of time where `x` is the `numOfNumers`. I would like it to only output for how many times it appears in both arrays.
Edit 2: 
Since I was recommended not to use pictures I would like it to show:
How many random numbers between 1 and 100: 1000
Which random number are you searching for?: 5

Unsorted List
5 found at location: 502
5 found at location: 725
5 found at location: 856
5 found at location: 924

Sorted List
5 found at location: 40
5 found at location: 41
5 found at location: 42
5 found at location: 43

Total of all numbers: 49089

What I am getting is 
Unsorted list
5 found at location 502 X1000
Sorted list 
5 found at location 41 X1000

Total of all numbers: 42013

Comment: "number appears in both the sorted and unsorted ArrayLists" hum .. there are the same element in both so  ..only the order is different, what do you mean ?

Comment: I will post pictures of the desired vs current for further clairifcation @azro

Comment: *"I will post pictures of the desired vs current for further clairifcation"* Please don't, no need for pictures. You can write it as you want text as your output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a condition that checks whether the current number (a or b) is equal to `searchNumber`. However, when an occurence is found you now try to print `randomNumbers.indexOf(searchNumber)`. This will for every occurence return the same number, namely the index of the first occurence. The only way to do this is to use a `for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++)` loop or use a counter.

Also i would place the "Unsorted List" and "Sorted List" above the loops so that those lines are only printed once.

If you use `for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++)`, your code will look something likes this:

```
    System.out.println("Unsorted List");
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++) {
        if (randomNumbers.get(i) == searchNumber) {
            System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: " + i);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(randomNumbers);

    System.out.println("Sorted List");
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++) {
        if (randomNumbers.get(i) == searchNumber) {
            System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: " + i);
        }
    }
```

Or if you want to use a counter:

```
    int loc = 0;
    System.out.println("Unsorted List");
    for(int a : randomNumbers) {
        if (searchNumber == a) {
            System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ loc);
        }
        loc++;
    }
    Collections.sort(randomNumbers);

    loc = 0;
    System.out.println("Sorted List");
    for(int b : randomNumbers) {
        if (searchNumber == b) {
            System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: " + loc);
        }
        loc++;
    }
```

Comment: That works perfectly. You said "or use a counter". The assignment would like me to use a for each loop could I use a counter with that and accomplish the same thing?

Comment: The second code piece uses a counter and should produce the same outcome.

Comment: The second one is exactly what was need the assignment calls for a for each loop even though it is kind of more work and would make more sense to use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to do is get a single output for EACH time in the
>   ArrayList that the number appears in both the sorted and unsorted
>   ArrayLists then a sum of all numbers in the array list.

Just add the if condition as shown below:

```
for(int a: randomNumbers)
{
    System.out.println("Unsorted List");
    if(a == searchNumber)
    {
        System.out.println(searchNumber + 
            " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(searchNumber));

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the changes you suggested but only getting a single value to show even when I did 100,000 random numbers between 1-100, 5 only shows one time when I am sure it appeared more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies here:

```
int searchNumber = stdIn.nextInt();
for(int a: randomNumbers)
{
    System.out.println("Unsorted List");
    System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(searchNumber)); 
}
Collections.sort(randomNumbers);

for(int b:randomNumbers)
{
    System.out.println("Sorted List");
    System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(searchNumber));  
}
```

You're reading a number in `searchNumber`, but never using it to compare against the numbers in `randomNumbers`, and you're printing every number in the array.

So, inside both `for-each` loops, you could:

```
if (searchNumber == a) {
    System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(a));
}
```

And the same with `b` variable.

I would also place: `System.out.println("Unsorted List");` before the loop...

So, it should look like:

```
System.out.println("Unsorted List");
for (int a : randomNumbers) {
    if (searchNumber == a) {
        System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(a));
    }
}

Collections.sort(randomNumbers);
System.out.println("Sorted List");
for (int b : randomNumbers) {
    if (searchNumber == b) {
        System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: "+ randomNumbers.indexOf(b));
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

Thanks to @ChrisWitteveen for pointing this out:

> One problem here is that randomNumbers.indexOf(a) and randomNumbers.indexOf(b) always return the same number.

In this case you could simplify your code by using a simple `for` loop instead of a `for-each` one:

Changing the above suggestion to:

```
System.out.println("Unsorted List");
randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>(randomNumbers);
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++) {
    if (searchNumber == randomNumbers.get(i)) {
        System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: " + i);
    }
}

Collections.sort(randomNumbers);
System.out.println("Sorted List");
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++) {
    if (searchNumber == randomNumbers.get(i)) {
        System.out.println(searchNumber + " found at location: " + i);
    }
}
```

Does the trick, for example I tried and changed the random generation from 1-100 to 1-10 for testing purposes and we get the following output, I also printed the whole list of numbers just for debugging purposes too:

```
How many random numbers between 1 and 100:20
2
9
2
6
10
5
6
6
7
6
9
9
3
7
9
5
10
3
6
8
Which random number are your searching for?:2

Unsorted List
2 found at location: 0
2 found at location: 2
Sorted List
2 found at location: 0
2 found at location: 1
128
```

Comment: One problem here is that `randomNumbers.indexOf(a)` and `randomNumbers.indexOf(b)` always return the same number.

Comment: Worked well except for the fact like I think Chris Witteveen was saying it returned the same locations for each 7 times. So I assume it appeared 7 times but its only showing the first location and mirroring it to all others.

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyJudge please see edit, working as desired :)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and patience with my stackoverflow newbieness this works perfectly but the for each with a counter was what was needed like @ChrisWitteveen did above.

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyJudge No worries, at least I think you learnt something :) That's the important thing here